# PHP returns symbol 'a' before '{' JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, syntax-error

I have this **PHP code:**

```
function _return($message, $status=200) {
    $return = json_encode([
        "message" => strval($message),
        "status" => intval($status)
    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo($return);
    exit();
}
```

Which returns in browser console `a{"message":"URL needed!","status":400}`

I don't understand where **the symbol 'a'** came from...

Due to this, AJAX can't process incoming data. (Calls error)

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            button.attr('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function(result, status, xhr) {
            console.log(result());
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            result = JSON.parse(result);
            if(result['status'] === 400) { 
                 errorNotification(result['message']);
            }
            successNotification("Successful!");
            button.attr('disabled', false);                
        },
        error: function(error) {
            errorNotification("Woops... Error!");
            console.log(error.responseText);
            button.attr('disabled', false);                
        }
    });
```

Comment: The `a` must be echoed in a previous part of the code, the `json_encode` doesn't have this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will need to find out whether this character originates from json_encode (it is not originated from there, but since you did not know about that, the logical step you need to make in order to see how this works is the following):

```
function _return($message, $status=200) {
    $return = json_encode([
        "message" => strval($message),
        "status" => intval($status)
    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo("TEEEEEST".$return);
    exit();
}
```

If the response would be

> TEEEEESTa{"message":"URL needed!","status":400}

(which will not be the case), then it would be an error in the generation of return. In reality the response will be

> aTEEEEEST{"message":"URL needed!","status":400}

which means that somewhere else in the project you have an echo, or an HTML between your PHP code tags which consists of that a letter. In order to locate where that happens you need to find out what the PHP code that is executed is and to echo different texts. If some text is echoed out before the a, that means that the problem is happening later. If something is echoed after the a, then that code line is executed after the problem occurred.